# c++: LLDB + Python - how to print a std::string in the python script

Tags: c++, lldb

I'm experimenting with LLDB + python in order to get better printing of json strings to a file. For a given std::string variable (call it buffer), I've tried the following within a python breakpoint script in order to pretty print to a file - all have been unsuccessful:

```
json.dump(frame.FindVariable("buffer"), handle, indent=4)
# ^^^^ error that SBValue* is not serializable
json.dump(frame.FindVariable("buffer").GetValue(), handle, indent=4)
# ^^^^ emits null
json.dump(frame.EvaluateExpression("buffer.c_str()"), handle, indent=4)
# ^^^^ error that SBValue* is not serializable
json.dump(frame.EvaluateExpression("buffer.c_str()").GetValue(), handle, indent=4)
# ^^^^ prints an address...not useful
json.dump(frame.EvaluateExpression("buffer.c_str()").GetData(), handle, indent=4)
# ^^^^ error that SBValue* is not serializable
```

Does anyone know what magic sauce will allow me to turn a std::string frame variable into a python string for passing to json.dump() ?

Comment: I found `>>> print(reg.description)` got the Object's description, when all I got from `>>> print(reg.value)` was a pointer.  You know this but I write it for others who end up on this SO page. Reference: https://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/lldb.SBValue-class.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the summary from the SBValue.  This page:

http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html

describes the summaries in more detail.  The SBValue.GetSummary call will do what you want.

Any time that lldb needs to convert from the actual but unhelpful value to a user friendly one it does this through the summary mechanism.  For instance, for a char *, 0x12345 is the actual value, but you really want to see "the contents of the C-string starting at 0x12345."  GetValue will show 0x12345, GetSummary the string.

Comment: ok - GetSummary() is tantalizingly close - but it appears to have some extra escaping of embedded quotes going on, thus messing with python's ability to load and dump as json. Just to be clear, the contents of the std::string are valid json and should be able to be parsed. I think the summary output if sanitizing the string for output in a way that makes it invalid json.

The thing I really want a way to turn the character buffer for the string (say , the .c_str() representation) into a native python string that can be passed around to other functions.

Comment: Ah, yes, GetSummary is for showing you the string as you would have typed it in C code, not the bytes.  To read the contents of a string buffer directly, you need to get the address of the buffer (c_str() returns that) then use SBProcess.ReadCStringFromMemory.

Comment: Thanks - ReadCStringFromMemory seems to do the trick, specifically:

     jstr = frame.GetThread().GetProcess().ReadCStringFromMemory(frame.EvaluateExpression("buffer.c_str()").GetValueAsUnsigned(), 0xffffff, e)

gives me a python string (in jstr) that I can then use. `e` is a variable of type lldb.SBError(). I'm going to mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 4):

Jim sent me in the right track above - the final code that worked for me is:

```
e = lldb.SBError()
frame.GetThread().GetProcess().ReadCStringFromMemory(frame.E‌​valuateExpression("b‌​uffer.c_str()").GetV‌​alueAsUnsigned(), 0xffffff, e)
```