# Is there a way to teach Android Studio how to display a C++ struct when hovering over the variable?

Tags: c++, android-studio

As a practical example, say I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct MyFoo {
    std::string mValue;
    bool hasValue;
    MyFoo() : hasValue(false) {}
    MyFoo(std::string value) : mValue(value), hasValue(true) {}
};
```

If I hover over an instance of this struct, Android Studio displays `+ ☰ {MyFoo}`. I can expand this, and with a little drilling down, see what the contents are. (I should note that this is an oversimplified example; my real-world application is a much more complicated struct, and seeing the value is not very easy).

Is there a way to somehow get it to display something like `+ ☰ {MyFoo} <none>` or `+ ☰ {MyFoo} "Hello, world"` instead?

I can see Android Studio doing this with some of the STL types, which suggests that somewhere there's knowledge on how to do this.

Bonus questions: How about XCode?

Comment: I did try implementing `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyFoo &mf)`, and while it did get me the effect I wanted when sending an object to ostream, it had no effect on what Android Studio displayed.

Comment: You're looking for what's called a pretty printer. I'm not a user of QT Creator, but [this page seems to discuss the care and feeding of pretty printers](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html) in QT Creator.

Comment: @user4581301 This doesn't seem to be about Qt Creator but about Android Studio.

Comment: How in the name of Crom did I go looking for QT creator? <expletive deleted>!

Comment: Yoiks. Well, they'll still be pretty printers.

Comment: @user4581301 "That's Crom, strong on his mountain!" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Android Studio uses LLDB for debugging native code.

You can use LLDB commands to add custom formatting for showing these variables.

See: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html

The easiest way to do fancy pretty-printing is a Python script inside LLDB (see the LLDB docs link for more info, I based this example off it)

```py
(lldb) type summary add -P MyFoo
Enter your Python command(s). Type 'DONE' to end.
def function (valobj,internal_dict,options):
   mval = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('mValue')
   hasval = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('hasValue')
   if hasval.GetValueAsUnsigned(0) == 0:
     return '<none>'
   else:
     return mval.GetSummary()
   DONE
```

Dealing with `std::string` is a real can of worms, but you can find some potential solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401848/c-lldb-python-how-to-print-a-stdstring-in-the-python-script).

Comment: Looks like I need to do some reading, but it looks like this is the answer I was looking for.